# Populating a list with Facebook Graph API objects

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, arraylist

I am trying to populate a String list with a JSON object from the Graph API containing the full_picture, message, and id fields of a facebook post. The problem is that my list doesn't seem to populate at all.

```
 String TAG = ImageIngester.class.getSimpleName();
    List<ImagePost> fbImages = new ArrayList<>();
    ImagePost fbImagePost;

    @Override
    public List<ImagePost> ingest() {

//    1. Reach out to Facebook SDK and get all image posts
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fields","posts{message,full_picture,object_id}");
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "me",
                bundle,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        //list of strings representing a JSON string
                        List<String> fbPosts = new ArrayList<>();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                            Log.d(TAG, jsonObject.toString());
                            for (int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                fbPosts.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                Log.d(TAG, fbPosts.toString());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                            for (int i = 0; i < fbPosts.size(); i++){
                                fbImages.add(i,fbImagePost);
                                Log.d(TAG, "added to ImagePost list");
                            }
                        Log.d(TAG, "post received");
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
        return fbImages;
        }
    }
```

I want the `fbPosts` list to start populating with the objects that I get from the GraphResponse, but it remains at size 0, and the only graph response I'm getting is my own ID.

Comment: Did you ask for `user_posts` permission?

Comment: Ah, thanks @CBroe, that was a missing piece of the puzzle. I had it set to "user_friends" before, forgetting that I was switching over to have it read my own posts instead. But even though GraphResponse now returns my own posts in the "data" array, the "fbPosts" array is still at size 0. So now that I've determined it's not the call to the Graph API that's the issue, it's something else perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking for response.data (which assues the FB graph call would return something like this)

```
{
    "data": {
    ....
    }
}
```

But in this case with Posts, when I ran your query

```
/me?fields=posts{message,full_picture,object_id})
```

through the GraphAPIExplorer on `developer.facebook.com`, it was returning the following:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "<MESSAGE WAS HERE>.",
        "full_picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/blah.jpg?oh=2020020202&oe=20202020202",
        "object_id": "30303030303",
        "id": "10101010101010101010"
      },
     ....
 ]}
}
```

So you're getting an empty array from "data" because data wasn't in the response key.

Try the following instead

```
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                ...
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("posts");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    ...
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ....
            }
```